# How can I make fonts in Thunderbird look bigger?

Tags: fonts, thunderbird

When I'm using Thunderbird with a 1080p resolution, it looks so small until zoomed. Is there any way to make messages look bigger permanently? Since the last Thunderbird update text cannot be forced to have a minimum size for all the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while moving the mousewheel when you are in the message read window?  That will instantly make the text larger or smaller for all messages.

You can also do it with the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>, or the **View > Zoom** menu.

Comment: Yes, but I was rather looking for something to avoid having to zoom every time!

Answer (score 1):

If using the preferences doesn't work for you, go to **Preferences** -> **Advanced** -> **Config Editor** and manually set all the `font.minimum-size` fields to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

For permanent changes in Thunderbird:

In the menubar, click on Edit -> Preferences.

In the preferences window, click on "Display", and then the "Formatting" tab.

Here you can change the default font and font size for e-mail messages.

[image]

This change will be permanent for all messages (unless you change it again of course).

Comment: Didn't work to me. Instead I had to go to "Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor" and manually set all the "font.minimum-size" fields to the desired value.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella Then there's something wrong with your installation.  You shouldn't have to "hack" it, and the settings in my answer should work fine.

Comment: The cause seems to be that your solution changes the value for all the fields, so it doesn't apply in some encodings. It would be noticeable only if you are using Thunderbird with a specific language or location.